# Safari csp google analytics not loaded due to img

Tags: google-analytics, safari, content-security-policy

I have an issue with my CSP in Safari (works fine in chrome though). I get the following error in the console.

> Refused to load
>   https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j47&aip=1&a=1433030850&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Flukasoppermann.com%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=vea.re%20%7C%20interface%20design%2C%20print%20design%2C%20branding%20%26%20information%20graphics%20%7C%20visionary%20design&sd=24-bit&sr=1440x900&vp=1440x746&je=1&_u=SCCAAEYgI~&jid=&cid=655577951.1480085859&tid=UA-7074034-1&z=695879907 because it does not appear in the img-src directive of the Content
>   Security Policy.

I don't really get why safari wants to load it as an img. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the tracking call to Google Analytics returns a 1x1 transparent gif. You can see this e.g. in the network tab of your browsers dev tools where the tracking call shows up as image (see the "type" column in the screenshot).

[image]

Comment: That does make sense. However, why is this not showing up in chrome?